# Деление на слоги, а не перенос.

Tags: слоги

Как по новым правилам правильно поделить на слоги слова: Чтенья, Учиться, Азбука, Букашка.Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Чтень-я(Сочетание сонорного согласного (Н)с шумным (j)между гласными имеет слогораздел внутри этого сочетания: пар-та, кол-ба, лом-кий, брон-за ), 
У-чи-ться, Аз-бу-ка, Бу-ка-шка.

Comment: Я стесняюсь спросить, а что значит "по новым правилам"?

Comment: Вероятно, имеется в виду, что раньше в школьной программе было только деление на слоги для переноса и про фонетический слог не говорилось, про закон восходящей звучности не упоминалось,слог составляли гласные и согласные буквы, а не звуки. А сейчас говорят о фонетическом слоге.